# Vue2 (2.5.17) Emit event from directive and listen in component thru slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

It might be over-complicated approach, but whats done its done. What I want is to emit custom event from a directive and listen for this even in parent component thru the slot.

But to the point -> The mockup project = https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-cray-76ytzl?file=/src/directives/input-control.vue

In the "input-control.vue", I am trying to emit custom event called "vcOnChange"

```
// Debounce might be improved for better user experience
el.addEventListener('input', _.debounce(() => {
    console.log('vnode:', vnode);
    const validationResult = vnode.formControl.validate();
    // This is tricky part
    emit(vnode, 'vcOnChange', { 'validators': validationResult});
    vnode.context.$emit('vcOnChange', { 'validators': validationResult});
}, 200));
```

The "emit" function looks more or less like this:

```
const emit = (vnode, name, data) => {
  var handlers = (vnode.data && vnode.data.on) || (vnode.componentOptions && vnode.componentOptions.listeners);

  if (handlers && handlers[name]) {
    handlers[name].fns(data);
  }
}
```

Not the tricky part. I would like to listen to this event from within parent component, when the component with my custom directive is imported via slot.

So in dummy example I've got something like this:

```
<custom-input>
    <template v-slot:label>
        Input label
    </template>

    <input type="text" novalidate v-form-control="inputFC" placeholder="placeholder">
    <template v-slot:hint>
        Some random hint
    </template>
    <template v-slot:errors>
        some random errors
    </template>
</custom-input>
```

The only solution that somewhat working is using vnode context, however it generates problem which event is emited to all elements binded with directive. Idk why is that happening to be honest, and I can't find any alternative solution. Is there a way to listen to a custom $emit from a default slot, while component have multiple named slots?

Comment: the reason why the event is emitted to all elements bound with the directive is likely because you're using vnode.context.$emit('vcOnChange', { 'validators': validationResult }); to emit the event. 

This emits the event on the context of the vnode, which may not be specific to the current instance of the directive. Instead, you should emit the event on the current instance using this.$emit('vcOnChange', { 'validators': validationResult });.

The approach you you can go for is Using Props and Events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason why the event is emitted to all elements bound with the directive is likely because you're using vnode.context.$emit('vcOnChange', { 'validators': validationResult }); to emit the event.

This emits the event on the context of the vnode, which may not be specific to the current instance of the directive. Instead, you should emit the event on the current instance using this.$emit('vcOnChange', { 'validators': validationResult });.

The approach you you can go for is Using Props and Events

In your directive:

```
const emit = (name, data) => {
    EventBus.$emit(name, data);   
}
```

In your parent component:

```
created() {
  EventBus.$on('vcOnChange', (data) => {
    // Handle the event here
  });
}
```

And don't forget to create the event bus:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

Remember to import the EventBus wherever you need to use it.

Comment: But isn't EventBus global? What I need is simple "emit", and I can even achieve what I want with my `emit(vnode, 'vcOnChange', { 'validators': validationResult});` function which code I provided. From this points I can access emit like this.$emit, but not from within a slot. Maybe this is my problem. How Can i listen do emit from "parent component"?

Comment: Yes, but your emit function is close to what you need. You can modify it to emit the event directly on the parent component by traversing up the Vue component tree until you find the parent component instance. Here's how you can do it:

const emit = (context, name, data) => {
  let parent = context.$parent;

  while (parent) {
    if (parent.$options._componentTag === 'parent-component') {
      parent.$emit(name, data);
      break;
    }
    parent = parent.$parent;
  }
};

Comment: Make sure to replace 'parent-component' with the actual tag name of your parent component. This way, the event will only be emitted to the specific parent component where you want to handle it, even if there are multiple instances of the directive in your application.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out. Thank you for your help. I doubt that we will see any more answers to this question, therefore I mark yours as correct one.